# how can I plan this sequence-1,2,2,3,4,4,5

Tags: python, range, sequence

I am fairly new to programming and I try to create the above mentioned sequence.
this problem is about having a strict length of elements which always progresses, this progression is inside the list by moving on the indexes. this strict length shifts from a set of indexes to the next one once all the indexes inside the strict length (not passing it's limits) are finished being scanned, and they are scanned in a format of "one after the other".
after all of that we come to the root of the problem:
once the strict length moves to another set, it starts from the last index that was previously, inside of the strict length but in the previous strict length.
the output of the root problem is the title of this post. I don't know how to solve the root problem.
this problem, involves "k" as an exponent of the strict length.
this is the script:

```
    strarr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
    k = 2
    n = 0
    while True:
      for i in range(k):
        print(strarr[n])
        n = n+1
      print(strarr[n])
```

the output I got is:
1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,10
and I don't know why I got such output, it doesn't seem logical.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand what you are looking for is to print the even numbers twice.
You can do the following without using a for loop by this way.

```
strarr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
k = 2
n = 0
while (n<10):
    if(int(strarr[n])%2 == 0):
        print(strarr[n])
        print(strarr[n])
    elif(int(strarr[n])%2 != 0):
        print(strarr[n])
    n = n+1
```

The reason why your code gives that output is because,
for the 1st iteration it would print 1, 2, 3
2nd iteration it would print out 3 again as there is another `print(stararr[n])` outside the for loop. That's the reason why you are getting the output you are getting.

```
    strarr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
    k = 2
    n = 0
    while True:
      for i in range(k):
        print(strarr[n])
        n = n+1
      print(strarr[n])
```

Answer (score 1):

The error that I think you're seeing has to do with the order that you print your output and update the index `n`. In the current, buggy code, you're printing first, then updating the value. This means that the second `print` outside of the inner loop prints using the next value of `n`, not the one you just used in the inner loop. The same index gets used a second time in the first pass of the inner loop the next time, but that's not the value you wanted to see repeated.

The solution to this issue is pretty simple. Rather than updating after you `print`, update before. You'll need to adjust the starting value of `n`, but that's no problem:

```
strarr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
k = 2
n = -1                          # change starting index
while True:
  for i in range(k):
    n = n+1                     # and reorder the lines in the inner loop
    print(strarr[n])
  print(strarr[n])
```

That said, the two loop thing is a lot more awkward than anything I'd really recommend. If you just want to repeat the odd-indexed values in the loop, you can do that much more simply:

```
for index in range(len(strarr)):
    print(strarr[index])
    if index % 2 == 1:
        print(strarr[index])
```

Or you can avoid directly needing to index at all, using `enumerate` to get the index and value of each element in the `for` statement itself. This is probably a more "Pythonic" way to solve the problem.

```
for index, value in enumerate(strarr):
    print(value)
    if index % 2 == 1:
        print(value)
```